# How can I Export my Java Project in Netbeans in Executable(.exe)?

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, packaging

I have completed my project but unable to export in executable form. I'm using Netbeans 12.

Comment: I don't recall Netbeans having the capability (beyond JavaFX I think, but I've never used it). You can use any number of third party tools which perform these actions, most of at least Ant intergration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who wanted to help me.

I got the solution myself and wanted to help new developers:

**For JDK 14+ with modern IDEs:**

> 1. Install JDK 14 or later on your system, if it's not already installed.
> 2. Open a terminal or command prompt and navigate to the directory
>    containing your Java application and its dependencies.
> 3. Build your application using a build tool such as Maven or Gradle.
>    Make sure to specify that you want to create a standalone executable
>    JAR file.
> 4. Once your application is built, navigate to the directory containing
>    the JAR file.
> 5. Run the jpackage command with the appropriate options to create a
>    native installer for your application. Here is an example command to
>    create a Windows MSI installer:

***Example:***

```
jpackage --input . --name MyApp --main-jar myapp.jar --type msi
```

> This command assumes that your application JAR file is named "myapp.jar" and that you want to create a Windows MSI installer with the name "MyApp".

**Here are some more examples and options for using jpackage to create native installers:**

> **Specify an icon for the installer:**

```
jpackage --input . --name MyApp --main-jar myapp.jar --type msi --icon myicon.ico
```

> **Specify an installer splash screen:**

```
jpackage --input . --name MyApp --main-jar myapp.jar --type pkg --splash splash.png
```

> **Include a custom JVM option:**

```
jpackage --input . --name MyApp --main-jar myapp.jar --type exe --java-options "-Xmx2g"
```

> **Set the installation directory**

```
jpackage --input . --name MyApp --main-jar myapp.jar --type dmg --app-image myapp.dmg --app-image-dir /Applications
```

> **Create a ZIP archive instead of an installer**

```
jpackage --input . --name MyApp --main-jar myapp.jar --type zip
```

**For JDK 8 with NetBeans 8.2: (old but works)**

> 1. Start an Ant based standard project
> 2. Enable native packaging inside Properties->Build->Deployment
> 3. Install [Inno setup tool](https://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php) for Exe, [Wix Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org) for Msi (similar package manager for other OS)
> 4. add bin paths of above tools as system environment variables
> 5. right click on project and select package as->Exe or MSI

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIcXE.png)

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32535362)

Answer (score 1):

Java applications aren't built as exe files but as jar files. The component that makes them executable is the Main-class attribute defined in the META-INF file of the jar.

In NetBeans to turn your program into an executable jar file

1)Right Click on your project->Properties->Select Run Tab on the left corner of your screen. You will see an text box saying main class, select the drop down arrow to browse through all main classes available in your project (Yes NetBeans can have multiple main classes but will run only one)

2)Optional Select the deployment tab and select compress jar to save space

3)Right Click on project->Clean and build

Then go to your projects folder on your file explorer you will see an dist(distribution)  folder and there you will see your built jar file named  (Project Name).jar simply double click it and the java jre will execute it

Some people have a problem running the jar file with double clicking in that case either from cmd or from an bat file type this script

```
set path=<path to your java.exe in your JDK/JRE bin folder>

cd (Path to where your jar file is located)

java -jar <Your Jar file>.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Files>Export>Browse to Export in netbeans.